# Modify Setup Menu Pops Up When Choosing an Interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I recently switched from Thonny to PyCharm environment. I installed python-3.8.0 from [www.python.org/](http://www.python.org/).

When I create a new project in PyCharm, I choose python-3.8.0.exe as Project Interpreter.

[image: Project interpreter selection]

But then, when I click on the "ok" button, a window "Modify Setup" appears:

[image: Modify setup window]

I don't understand how to fix that in order to compile a simple piece of code.

Comment: point it to where you __installed__ python. I think the one you're pointing to is the installer. Because, PyCharm is just executing the executable pointed.

Comment: Yes that was probably the problem, thank you ;)